# jQuery UI datepicker: How to call "$.datepicker._gotoToday;" from own button?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need to call `$.datepicker._gotoToday;` from my own button.

I'm adding the custom button in this way:

```
beforeShow: function (input) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var bodyPane = $(input).datepicker("widget");

            $("<button>", {
                click: function () {
              // call $.datepicker._gotoToday;
                }
            }).attr("class", "btnToday").text("test").appendTo(bodyPane);
        }, 1);
    }
```

Is there a way to call the function or "clone" it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just set the date for the picker in the click function:

```
$(input).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(function(){
  $("#id_input").datepicker({
     showButtonPanel: true,
     changeMonth: true,
     changeYear: true
   });
});
$('#id_input').click(function(){
  $('.ui-datepicker-current').trigger('click');
  $('.ui-datepicker-buttonpane').hide();
});
```

it's ok for me ;)